# Error retrieving parent item for ____, cannot resolve symbol r

Tags: android

Started a new Android project, After the default code that was given said `could not resolve symbol r`, I did a `sync project with gradle files` and then got these messages:

> Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Inverse'.
>
> Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Button.Colored'.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear to understand what you want is ...... its approximate answer. I think you updated your android studio but not the SDK open your SDK & check its status. if Android 6.0 (API 23) is available install its features...... & then open build.gradle file under the Gradle script category at the left in android studio & check its code, code should be something like this

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.inzi.app"
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
  }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
     }
  }

 dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0'
}
```